# Javascript of apk built by cordova CLI doesn't work on emulator/device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I have started to learn `PhoneGap/Cordova` to create app for mobile devices.

I created test app (cordova create) and added javascript file with simple function.

**file test1.js:**

```
function doalert() {
    alert("Test1 alert!");
}
```

Then I put button into generaten index.html + included mentioned js script file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>rth Test1</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <button type="button" onclick="doalert()">Alert</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, button should invoke the doalert() function, which displays alert.

**Here is the problem:**
 
If I build this project into android application (apk) and install it on emulator or on my device, it doesn't work as expected. Application launches and shows *"Device is ready"*. But, tapping on button doesn't do anything (looks like the JavaScript function is not called).

If I run it from browser (Firefox) or if I use PhoneGap server - client applications, then everything works fine.

I have checked inside of apk, and all files seems to be in place.

**Using below software versions:**

```
Android: 4.4.4
Cordova: 4.0.0
```

Comment: Put the button tag above the two scripts

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I tried several combinations of placement of button and tag and test1.js script tag. Nothing was successful.

Comment: Ok then delete all of the generated HTML that Cordova did for you and write your own.

Comment: I have made it work. However in some strange way. Instead of installing and using Cordova CLI (it is marked outdated on PhoneGap pages) I have installed PhoneGap CLI directly (http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli/install/). If app is built directly using PhoneGap CLI, it works ok.